# Run Linux commands from Daemon

Tags: c++, c, linux, daemon

I need to run a linux command such as "df" from my linux daemon to know free space,used space, total size of the parition and other info.  I have options like calling system,exec,popen etc..

1. But as this each command spawn a new process  , is this not possible to run the commands in the same process from which it is invoked?
2. And at the same time as I need to run this command from a linux daemon, as my daemon should not hold any terminal. Will it effect my daemon behavior?

Or is their any C or C++ standard API for getting the mounted paritions information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no *standard* API, as this is an OS-specific concept.

However,

1. You can parse `/proc/mounts` (or `/etc/mtab`) with (non-portable) [`getmntent`/`getmntent_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getmntent) helper functions.
2. Using information about mounted filesystems, you can get its statistics with [`statfs`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/statfs).

Comment: @siri, I have updated the answer with a better option (and yes it will).

Comment: And I just want to confirm whether running a command from daemon is right or wrong and what side effects it may have

Comment: @siri it's certainly not wrong. For example `cron` runs its jobs with `fork()`+`exec()`. But `df` uses `statfs`, so it's a more direct way.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it useful to explore the `i3status` program source code: http://code.stapelberg.de/git/i3status/tree/src/print_disk_info.c

To answer your other questions:

> But as this each command spawn a new process , is this not possible to run the commands in the same process from which it is invoked?

No; entire 'commands' are self-contained programs that must run in their own process.

Depending upon how often you wish to execute your programs, `fork();exec()` is not so bad. There's no hard limits beyond which it would be better to gather data yourself vs executing a helper program. Once a minute, you're probably fine executing the commands. Once a second, you're probably better off gathering the data yourself. I'm not sure where the dividing line is.

> And at the same time as I need to run this command from a linux daemon, as my daemon should not hold any terminal. Will it effect my daemon behavior?

If the command calls `setsid(2)`, then `open(2)` on a terminal without including `O_NOCTTY`, that terminal [might](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html) become the controlling terminal for that process. But that wouldn't influence your program, because your program already disowned the terminal when becoming a daemon, and as the child process is a session leader, it cannot change your process's controlling terminal.